# Are there any unicorns/dwarves in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are there any unicorns in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim?
In The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion I have found unicorns. But I don't know if they exist in Skyrim.

Also, there are rumours about dwarves in the game. But has anyone seen any?

Comment: You could improve your question by changing its formatting. `All the grey text doesn't help if it's too much.`

Comment: So what dose down vote mean?

Comment: That people don't consider this a 'good' question, for a variety of reasons. However, if they don't comment, you can't improve it. It may be beneficial to edit out the dwarven part, since that's easy to find on the unofficial wiki's and Google (maybe make that a seperate question)

Comment: i once found a unicorn however the horn did look like one of my lost arrows :O

Comment: It's Hard to me chose answer(all correct), so I decide to choose oldest one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dwarves (or Dwemer) in Skyrim have been "extinct" for a long time, the only remains of them are their ruins and automatons. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dwemer

I'm not sure about Unicorns, but I haven't seen any yet.

And there is nothing on the wiki: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Unicorn#Unicorn

Comment: It's important to note that the "dwarves" didn't physically resemble the dwarves of most other fantasy - that is, they weren't short or stocky. The best examples in Skyrim of what the Dwemer would have looked like before they disappeared would probably be the High Elves, or else the last pair of Snow Elves (pre-deformation Falmer) encountered in the Dawnguard DLC.

Answer (score 9):

According to the UESP [unicorns](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Unicorn) were present in [Oblivion only](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Bestiary_U) and can't be found in Skyrim. To the best of my knowledge there has only been one living dwarf present in any of the Elder Scrolls games and that was [Yagrum Bagarn](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Yagrum_Bagarn) in Morrowind.

Answer (score 9):

As far as the Dwarfs (or Dwemer) are concerned: they are an extinct species of elf, whose names mostly end in `-mer`:

- [Aldmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Aldmer) (a.k.a. Elder Folk)
- [Altmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Altmer) (a.k.a. High Elves)
- [Ayleid](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Ayleids) (a.k.a. Wild Elves, Heartland High Elves)
- [Bosmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Bosmer) (a.k.a. Wood Elves)
- [Chimer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Chimer) (a.k.a. Changed Folk)
- [Dunmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dunmer) (a.k.a. Dark Elves)
- [Dwemer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dwemer) (a.k.a. Dwarves, or Deep Folk)
- [Falmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Falmer) (a.k.a. Snow Elves)
- [Maormer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Maormer) (a.k.a. Sea Elves or Tropical Elves)
- [Orc](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Orc) (a.k.a. Orsimer, or Pariah Folk)

(List lifted directly from [the UESP page on Races](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Races))

Please note that as direct descendants of the Aldmeri-Nedic Manmer, Bretons are sometimes known by that name: Manmer.

The only thing left of the Dwemer as far as I know are the ruins of their cities and some of their mechanical creations.

I don't believe there is a unicorn in Skyrim.

Comment: Oi. Don't forget the Dunmer. People always forget the Dunmer...

Comment: @Tom not nearly as often as they forget the Orsimer... They call them the Pariah Elves for a reason... :(

Comment: I am so terribly sorry! I shall update my answer as soon as I have found the time to compile an exhaustive list of (extinct) Elven species.

Comment: @TomWright Gentlemen, I have updated my answer. I hope it is to your liking.

Comment: And another ping @LessPop_MoreFizz

Comment: @zsub, Great List!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to shell out some cash, and if you have Special Edition, you can now have a Unicorn in your game.  The Creation Club content [Wild Horses](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wild_Horses) provides a Unicorn:

> A [Unicorn](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unicorn) can also be tamed at the conclusion of the quest [Creature of Legend](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creature_of_Legend)